# greenplum -> greenplum data pumping

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I got a one-time task to upload ~50 datatables (about 1 TB in total) from 1 greenplum system to another. Administrators have already allowed a network connection between the systems. Also i have link and user at remote gp system.

Google gives several ways:

1. - https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/wiki/Greenplum-to-Greenplum
2. - https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum-Data-Copy-Utility/2.6/greenplum-copy/gpcopy-migrate.html
3. - https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum/5/greenplum-database/best_practices-data_loading.html#external-tables
4. - https://www.greenplumdba.com/gptransfer-utility-in-greenplum

Each of these methods involves configuring and installing third-party software/extension on a server with administrator rights, or intermediate data upload to csv.

How can I make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details of your Greenplum cluster, as this will help provide better direction.

Key information would be:

**Source Cluster:**

- Greenplum version
- number of segment hosts
- number of data segments per host

**Destination Cluster:**

- Greenplum version
- number of segment hosts
- number of data segments per host

**Additional Questions:**

- Is there any shared storage accessible from both Greenplum clusters (NFS, s3, etc? )

In general, your most viable options will be the `gpcopy` (2. in your list above) or the `gpbackup/gprestore` utilities (not listed above).  External tables (3. above) generally are not used in this use case, and  `gptransfer` (4. above) has been depracated for years, in favor of `gpcopy` and does not exist in Greenplum 6.x or Greenplum 7.x

Comment: source system: PostgreSQL 9.4.24 (Greenplum Database 6.14.0 build commit:62d24f4a423236cab4bf2ca4538e96dcf58db8ba Open Source) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 6.4.0, 64-bit compiled on Feb  5 2021 18:58:52 

target: PostgreSQL 9.4.26 (Greenplum Database 6.21.3 build commit:622fa9a831d111db91b0e2c338f1379d7d5f6e9d Open Source) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 6.4.0, 64-bit compiled on Oct 27 2022 17:36:45

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't enough information to provide guidance.  By answering the questions above, we can give provide better options